# Help reading DP4T slide switch schematic

Tags: switches

I am having trouble reading the schematic for the C&K L204011MS02Q DP4T slide switch ([datasheet here](https://www.digikey.com/en/datasheets/ck/ckl)). In particular, I am trying to identify the "common" pins so that I can wire this switch up correctly on my PCB.

[image]

Looking at the schematic for the L202 DPDT switch in the same datasheet, I can see that pins 2 and 5 are the "common" pins - in each of the two available slide switch positions, the switch is connecting pins 2 and 5 to other pins (pins 1 and 4 or pins 3 and 6, respectively).

[image]

In the schematic shown in [this datasheet](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/C&K/SS-24E06-TG_5_(P).pdf) for another DP4T switch, the C&K SS-24E06-TG 5 (P), I can see that the center pins of each row are the "common" pins - in each of the four available slide switch positions, these center pins are connected to other pins.

[image]

Returning to the L204 DP4T switch, which pins would be the "common" pins? Many thanks for any help - I have searched far and wide on the internet and consulted with two coworkers and still can't seem to figure this schematic out. Also, I don't currently have access to the switch to buzz the pinout manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The black part slides in to any of 4 different positions, making connections as follows.

Pos A: 1 to 2 and 6 to 7

Pos B: 2 to 3 and 7 to 8

Pos C: 3 to 4 and 8 to 9

Pos D: 4 to 5 and 9 to 10

So, it looks like some Boolean algebra needs to be worked out to achieve at best a single pole 4 throw switch.

Is enough for your purposes?  You might want to go to a different type of switch.  From what I see, the manufacture called it a DP4T switch, but it's really a 4 position slide switch with sequential contacts.

Comment: I suspect you may be right. The manufacturer's naming is unfortunate because people looking for a DP4T switch find this one and people looking for a 4 position slide switch with sequential contacts might not find it. I am in contact with the tech team at Digikey and will provide an update/confirm the answer once they get back to me.

Comment: So I ended up ordering one of these switches and buzzing the pinout manually with a multimeter. The pinout was exactly as you described, i.e., a four position switch with sequential contacts. I ended up selecting [another DP4T switch](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/SS-24E06-TG+5+(P)/CKN10394-ND/2747191) that offered dedicated common pins. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks man.  Keep on keeping on!

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at the same switch for the same purpose.  Finally I figured it out *after a couple of hours trying*!!!

- A to pins 2 and 9.
- B:

  - B1 to pin 1,
  - B2 to pin 3,
  - B3 to pin 8,
  - B4 to pin 10!

One source, 4 destinations!